# Microsoft VC++ Runtime Library : abnormal termination

Tags: visual-c++

we are using VC ++ dll in VB 6.0 application. it was working good in current server. but we plan to deploy the application in new server.

Now when tried to execute the vb6.0 application it is throwing abnormal erro and closes the vb 6.0 application.

I tried to install VC++ redistributable package 2005 & higher.. but it is not working..

Please giude me to pick the correct version of Redistributable package for VB 6.0

Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the Dependancy Walker(Depends.exe). This application will show you what are all the dependancies needed for your VC++ DLL.

2) It will show you a list of DLLs. Copy those dlls to the directory where VC++ DLL exists.

3) If it s an VC++ MFC DLL built with "shared dll" option then you might need some MFC dlls to be copied.

4) Also check with the correct C runtime library file MSVCRT*.dll. This file might also be required. Although **depends** will show you all these dependancies.

5) **Depends** will show whether there is a dependancy of C Runtime Library.

Comment: how can i check the C runtime library. (i.e) which version of the dll needs to be placed for the dll

Comment: Actually, the dependency walker is particularly *bad* at figuring out dependencies for side-by-side DLLs like MFC.

Comment: Hi Pruthviraj, checked the version of the dll. VC++ dll expecting MSCVRT.dll (6.1.8638) but in system it is having (7.0.3790).. will this cause problem?